# How to parse dates?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

the date format  what i have is:

```
2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200
```

but I require: `2006-04-01`

not able to recognize from UNIX timestamp format

```
valid_wdf
  .withColumn("MYDateOnly", to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Formatted Date","yyyy-MM-dd"))))
  .show()
```

moreover it says something like this:

> org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result
> due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '2006-04-01
> 00:00:00.000 +0200' in the new parser. You can set
> spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior
> before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid
> datetime string.

I want to know why this library is used..if any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the following query in Spark 3.0.1 and review the exception.

```
Seq("2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200")
  .toDF("d")
  .select(unix_timestamp($"d","yyyy-MM-dd"))
  .show
```

The exception does say the cause of the SparkUpgradeException, but you have to look at the bottom of the stack trace where it says:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:150)
...
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
  at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
  at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1874)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:78)
  ... 140 more
```

There is "unparsed text found at index 10" since the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` does not cover the remaining part of the input date.

Consult [Datetime Patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for valid date and time format patterns. The easiest seems to use `date_format` standard function.

```
val q = Seq("2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200")
  .toDF("d")
  .select(date_format($"d","yyyy-MM-dd")) // date_format
scala> q.show
+--------------------------+
|date_format(d, yyyy-MM-dd)|
+--------------------------+
|                2006-04-01|
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: ```after using the date format....i get one day before the actual date 2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200|2006-03-31|```